# mysql query with when statement comparing

Tags: mysql, compare

I want to write mysql when statement and i can't do it.

explanation => localParty is column in table "data", loc is column from table "o", and i want to compare localParty to loc, if their values are equal then i want to retrieve information from loc_m column (this column is from table "o"), and if not equal then from localParty column (from "data" table)

Please help how to write this script in mysql query ? Thanks

with this script

```
select (case when data.localparty = o.loc then o.loc_m else data.localparty end) 
    as customdata from data, o
```

it is working but it is missing exactly three result ( I mean that then data.localparty equal to o.loca it is giving result from data.localparty 3 times and after it one time it is giving result from loc_m  and it is going like so .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could modify the query in the following way:

```
SELECT IF(t1.Column1 = t2.Column2,t2.Column1,t1.Column3) FROM TABLE1 AS t1, Table2 AS t2
```

Comment: thats understand well ,thanks , but how it would be with when statement, because with if not every given value returns like it must be, because i am retrieving many and i think because of it is missing some result with IF statement

Comment: to say with other words , this script work but missing exactly 3 values ( I mean that it is retrieving data from column1 3 times accordingly when column1 equal to column2) and why ?

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
select (case when data.localparty = o.loc then o.loc_m else data.localparty end) 
as customdata from data, o
```

Comment: It's just a name for the calculated column OR a column alias.

Comment: i have very interesting situation , this scripts work only with some data , because it is missing some result. I am retrieving data with this script and it is retrieving data from localparty too when it is equal to o.loc and why ?

Answer (score 1):

you can use following query

```
Select O.loc_m as local 
from Data 
inner join on O on data.localparty=O.loc
UNION
Select data.loacalparty as local 
from Data 
where data.localparty is not in (select loc from O )
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [control-flow functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html) to achieve that goal:

```
SELECT IF(Column1 = Column2,Column1,Column3) FROM TABLE1
```

Comment: but column1 and column2,column3 are from diff tables, and how specify this syntax , i can not guess it

Comment: lets say that column1 is from table1 and (column2 and column3) from table2 . how write marked script with this tables ?